# How do I code a login portal with no serverside code?

Tags: javascript, authentication

Is there any way to code a simple login page; one that:

You have to type in one password and one username from a list to let you through,
the code has to work in an html  tag,
it doesn't require an entirley new file in the website source

Comment: No. (Not one that's secure)

Comment: If by simple you mean an easily bypassed and insecure login form, yes it is possible.

Comment: Anything downloaded by the browser you should consider as *public* information.  And since authentication requires a *private* portion, you cannot do this by definition.  It would be a bit like having a button on a page with the text next to it "Only authorized people may proceed.  Authorize yourself by clicking on the button."  You can see where there might be problems...

Comment: meh, i'll probably code one with php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not very practical but...

Yes, it is entirely possible and it's possible to write it in a way that it will be secure. You will however not be able to authenticate against a server.

To make the point: imagine that the password is the entire website's source.

Here is a simple scheme that does that:

- Use a [library that provides asymmetric encryption](https://github.com/travist/jsencrypt) to encrypt any storage you're using (`localStorate` for instance) to keep secrets.
- The user's password is the private encryption key - the user enters it to decrypt the site and the data.

A lot of more complicates schemes exist for this - read them, don't roll your own crypto scheme.
Do not download anything sensitive over the wire - like I said earlier, it's not secure.

Use the CSP and tell users they should not use your site with any extensions or userscripts installed.

To be crystal clear **you must authenticate against any server you work against regardless of this**.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the server, you can password protect the directory, which will automatically prompt for a username and password in the browser. This wouldn't require any code changes. Otherwise, you're going to need server-side code to provide secure login.

The problem is that everything on the client-side--HTML and JavaScript--is accessible to users. If your usernames and passwords were stored in plain text, anyone would be able to view the list. Even if they were encoded or hashed, all of the decoding/validation logic would be visible, making the page easy to hack.

Comment: Here, this is an RSA encoded message, I'm completely exposing it to you and letting you know what the decoding logic is (rsa decrypt) - what's the message: http://paste.ubuntu.com/10518006/